# How to find all lines containing specific string in 1000 file using a bash script and write them to text file with minor changes?

Tags: bash, grep

I wrote a small script that find a line containing specific string I provide to the bash and write them to a text file.

```
 grep -A $2 "$1" outFile.txt >> "$1-results.txt"
```

Now I want the search to be applied to 1000 file but the results will be in one text file.

The second thing I want is before starting the search of every file to write add a heading  ' FILE 1 ' and when when File 1 finishes I add 'FILE 2' etc.

I have found [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23545/how-to-insert-a-new-line-after-every-second-line) but they did not work with me in a file , the worked on the terminal only. I tried to make some modification but I faild.

**Update:**

Directory has the following files:

```
res1.txt ........ res1000.txt
```

Input as an example:

```
Jhon Age
```

Which mean get any person with the name jhon and bring his age with the name.

Expected out put :

```
      FILE1
 Jhon      43
 Jhon      55 
      FILE2
  Jhon     66
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
     FILE3
      .
      .
      .
```

etc..

Comment: Please post sample input files and expected output samples in code tags into your post please.

Comment: `grep -H` is better than adding headers: it'll prepend every search result with file name, no need to look it up, easy filtering/counting and such.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171314/how-to-grep-for-same-string-but-multiple-files-at-the-same-time

Comment: What's wrong with `grep -A "$2" "$1" *.txt >> results.txt`?

Comment: it says no such file or directory *.txt. And I could not format the results as I want in the text file. Or probably I don't know how Got my point?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Not a possible duplicate, very different request.

Comment: @ushehri, it's not clear from your question where those 1000 file(names) come from? If they are all under one directory, you can use `grep -R` to grep recursively. The `*.txt` was only an example if you wanted to grep all txt files. So, what is your input, and what is the expected output?

Comment: Update Question

Comment: So, what specifically is it you're stuck with? [Just asking for code for your specific case is off topic 'cuz it's not reusable.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338499/648265)

Comment: The duplicate tells you how to get the file name output. Refactoring it to produce the file name on a separate output line is a simple matter of rewriting the output.

Comment: @tripleee, I want to write my self "FILE1" or any other string as as I like . so please it not even close to the duplicate. .

Comment: I added a second duplicate which addresses that part.

Comment: @tripleee You just in love with duplicates

Comment: Is there still a problem or did you manage to solve your task with these links?

Comment: I did solve it by using java as helper class

Answer (score -1):

I think it's what you look for

```
for i in *.txt;do
  result=$(grep -A "$2" "$1" "$i")
  [ $? -eq 0 ] && { echo "$i"; echo "$result"; }
done
```

Comment: I think you can't get expected output with grep 'pattern' *.txt